# Is that possible to install docker desktop on citrix VDI

Tags: docker, windows-10, citrix

Is there a possibility to install the docker on the Citrix VDI. Showing the error message states that Enable Virtualization on the BIOS settings.

Able to install the wsl2 and enabled the windows features for Hyper-V, WSL and Virtualization